# Generalized n-pars macro I/O template

Tags: batch-file

I have coded a generalized macro that accept up to N I/O parameters (however more than 8) and I would like to share it to see if it is correct and to possibly improve it with the suggestions of the community of stackoverflow.
Below the code:

```
:: Define CR as Carriage Return
for /f %%C in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%C"

:: Define LF as a Line Feed (newline) string
set LF=^


::Above 2 blank lines are required - do not remove

::define a newline with line continuation
:: set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^" this is an old style and more complex \n definition
:: Next is the modern style \n definition
(set \n=^^^
%=EMPTY=%
)

set @{macroNparIOTemplate}=for %%. in (1 2) do if %%.==2 (for %%L in ("!LF!") DO ( %\n%
    set /a "I=1" %\n%
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%1 in ("!args: =%%~L!") do (%\n%
        set "par.!I!=!%%1!" %\n%
        set /a "I+=1" %\n%
      )%\n%
      %= Begin macro =% %\n%
      %= End macro   =% %\n%
      endlocal ^&(%\n%
        %= Below output parameters that cross the endlocal barrier =% %\n%
        set "out1=value1"%\n%
        set "out2=value2"%\n%
      )%\n%
)) else setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion ^& set args=

:: Below the call to the macro
%@{macroNparIOTemplate}% inPar1 inPar2 ... inParX ... outPar1 outPar2 ... outParY
```

Comment: Stack overflow is for help with code that is not functioning as expected. [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the site on StackExchange where this type of question belongs. Please delete and post there.

Comment: This question belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In fact my code doesn't work so I'm asking for help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you define an array to Par.`n`, yet you dont use this array to return values.

An alternative is to rebuild the argument list into an indexed list, then build the array from that list after crossing the endlocal barrier:

```bat
@Echo off

(Set \n=^^^
%= DNR =%
)

 %= Doublequote ALL arguments. =%
 %= '*' CANNOT be parsed. =%
 %= '""Arg String""' CANNOT be parsed =%
 %= '"' Doublequotes within Args MUST be escaped - '^"' and balanced. =%
 %= Returns values to $RV prefix. Substring modify to specify return var. =%
 Set $Macro=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (%\n%
  Set "$RV.Arg[i]=0"%\n%
  Set "$RV.Return="%\n%
  For %%G in (!$Macro.In!)Do (%\n: Process each Arg below. Terminate each line with \n variable. =%
   Set /A "$RV.Arg[i]+=1"%\n%
   Set "$RV.Return=!$RV.Return! "$RV.Arg[!$RV.Arg[i]!]=%%~G""%\n%
  )%\n%
  Set "$RV.Return=!$RV.Return! "$RV.Arg[i]=!$RV.Arg[i]!""%\n%
  For /f "Delims=" %%v in ("!$RV.Return!")Do (Endlocal ^& For %%O in (%%v)Do Set %%O)%\n%
 )Else Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion ^& Set $Macro.In=

 %$macro:$RV=Example[1]% "Arg 1" "Arg 2"

 %= Escaping requirements =%
 %$macro:$RV=Example[2]% "^^^!,^^^^,%%" "Arg with ^"quoted^" component"

 Set Example
```

[See here](https://pastebin.com/gzL7AYpC) For a more advanced template that is designed for both switch and arg handling - Note however it does not internally handle setlocal / endlocal - it instead makes use of Internal macro specific prefixes to prevent variable conflict. Also, the heavy use of Substring modification further limits the natural use of poison characters in argument strings / switch values.

A practical application that demonstrates the use of the template can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/zjwgdZiM)

Comment: I sense the power of the technique but I am far from fully understanding it

Comment: in the example pastebin.com/gzL7AYpC I can view the setlocal enabledelayedexpansion but I can't view the endlocal is this an error

Comment: Endlocal is implicit when `goto :Eof` is used.

Comment: But isn't it better to embed the setlocal enabledelayedexpansion and endlocal commands into the macro itself?

Comment: Perhaps in some niche situation where for some reson the script executing the macro needs Delayed Expansion `Disabled`, otherwise the approach of using a Macro specific variable naming / prefix structure avoids the primary issue of variables inadvertantly having their value changed.

Comment: For complex macros that define many variables, embedding setlocal / endlocal can be restrictive due to the way the values are passed back - [ by capturing the delayed value of a !variable! into a `for` loop metavariable immediately prior to `endlocal` ; then iterating over the metavariable value to assign in the parent environment. ]

Answer (score 2):

Some points about macro problems.

- Use inside macros a specific variable prefix to avoid collisions
- exit the setlocal scope (`crossing the endlocal barrier`) is only simple for simple content like numbers or alphanumeric only

The collision problem would occur in your code when you use something like

```
set myParam1=content1
set I=content2
set par.1=content3
%@{macroNparIOTemplate}% myParam1 I par.1
```

It can be avoided by *resered* macro prefixes, like `@`:

```
    set "@par.!@I!=!%%1!" %\n%
    set /a "@I+=1" %\n%
```

The local scope exit problems are visible with content like.

```
set "myParam=^&!"^&!"
```